# EJB 3 Transaction Boundaries: Calling Non Transactional Class

Tags: java, transactions, ejb-3.0

I have an EJB 3 bean. In which the transaction management is container managed and the transactional attribute is required.

From one method of this bean I am instantiating another class, which is non-transactional and calling a method to delegate the persist task. In this method I am passing `EntityManager` instance, which is injected by the `PersistanceContext` in the above bean. Now when I am calling the `EntityManage#persist` I am getting exception saying:

> The operation needs to be executed within a transaction

I am suspecting the cause of this exception is due to the Transaction is not available in this second class. Am I right?

If I don't want to change the code flow, is there alternate any way to achieve this?

Comment: Post your code. That should work fine. Also post the persistence.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right. `persist()` needs to be called within a transaction. In some way, you have to remove the call to persist. Else, you might be forced to transform some of the non-transactional classes into Enterprise JavaBeans themselves.